# Is the sort order of jQuery's $().each() guaranteed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

On one page of my site I have have a list of entries created by the user - standard HTML `<ul>` with `<li>` elements inside it.

I want to iterate through the list, but the order of elements is important.

Using jQuery `$('.myList li').each()`, can I guarantee that I will get the `li` elements in the order that they appear in the DOM?

From my tests so far, it appears that they do get iterated in the correct order, but I can't find anything that tells me it's guaranteed.

If it isn't guaranteed, what would be the next best alternative method for iterating through them in order?

Comment: not duplicate but could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099759/does-the-order-of-the-elements-in-the-jquery-wrapped-set-always-match-the-order

Answer (score 101, accepted):

So after reading the docs and coming away still not quite certain, I ended up diving in an actually reading the jQuery source code (thanks to @RoryMcCrossan's answer for prompting me on that).

In fact (contrary to what @RoryMcCrossan said), `$().each()` uses either `for...in` or `for`, **depending on whether the input is an object or an array**.

For 'array', it suffices to be an 'array-like' object, which is the case for a jQuery object because it contains a numbered list of elements and a `length` property.

Therefore, a call to `$().each()` will use `for` and not `for...each` as it is iterating over a jQuery object. And since we're using `for`, we know that we can guarantee the order of iteration for `$().each()` will match the order of the elements it is given.

So that leads me to ask a follow-up question of whether the order of elements given by the original query is guaranteed to be the same as they appear in the DOM. If so, then I should be okay.

The answer to that can be found in the [question linked in the comments by @Mritunjay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099759/does-the-order-of-the-elements-in-the-jquery-wrapped-set-always-match-the-order), and the answer is 'yes, they are returned in the order that they appear in the DOM.

So the final answer is that yes, I can use `$('.myList li').each()` and iterate through the list items in the order that they appear in the DOM.

Thanks for the help and the prompts guys. Much appreciated.

Comment: Of course, you do realize that digging the answer out of the code is not a guarantee that the **undocumented** behavior won't change in the future. If it was my project, I would find a way to actually guarantee the desired behavior, assuming `$().each()` is not guaranteed to execute in the desired order.