# jQuery highlight menu item when scrolled over section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to highlight the menu item when you scroll down to the section.
The highlighting works but for some reason I can't remove the highlighting when scrolled to an other section

This is what my menu looks like:

```
<div id="navbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a data-id="home" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-right"><a data-id="cont" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-right"><a data-id="exp" href="#exp">Expertise</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-right"><a data-id="wie2" href="#wie2">Wie</a></li>
          </ul>
</div>
```

In the html for every section where I use the id anchor I added `class="section"`

This is my jQuery:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        var position = jQuery(this).scrollTop();

        jQuery('.section').each(function() {
            var target = jQuery(this).offset().top;

            var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');

            if (position >= target) {
                jQuery('#navbar>ul>li>a').removeClass('clicked');
                jQuery('#navbar ul li a[data-id=' + id + ']').addClass('clicked');
            }
        });
});
```

Anyone has any idea why the class get deleted everytime? becuase when I comment out `jQuery('#navbar>ul>li>a').removeClass('clicked');` it works great. The classes are being added correctly. But removing them doesn't work :(

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/32395988/5247200

Answer (score 1):

Havent tested this, but i think this should work

```
  jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        var position = jQuery(this).scrollTop();

        jQuery('.section').each(function() {
            var target = jQuery(this).offset().top;

            var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
            jQuery('#navbar ul li a[data-id=' + id + ']').removeClass('clicked');
            if (position >= target) {
                jQuery('#navbar ul li a[data-id=' + id + ']').addClass('clicked');
            }
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think because: `#navbar>ul>li>a` is not the same as `#navbar ul li a`

The first is trying to find direct `<ul>` child to #navbar and the second is asking to find a `<ul>` child (at any level) under #navbar and the same goes for the rest of the selector.

Have a look [here](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

> The child combinator (E > F) can be thought of as a more specific form
>   of the descendant combinator (E F) in that it selects only first-level
>   descendants.

Comment: **does not fixes the issue**.

Comment: So what didn't fix the issue !? can you tell me what you did !!

Comment: Did you mean that this doesn't work:
jQuery('#navbar ul li a').removeClass('clicked');

Comment: @TarekN.Elsamni not the syntax but just the line of code. When I comment it out the classes are being added correctly when I undo the comment the classes aren't being added they get constantly removed

Answer (score 0):

Hard for me to tell exactly what the issue is without being able to dig through the actual code, but you could try updating this line:

```
jQuery('#navbar>ul>li>a').removeClass('clicked');
```

to:

```
jQuery('#navbar').find('clicked').removeClass('clicked');
```

That way you are for sure going to be removing the class "clicked" from only link that already has the class "clicked" before reassignment.

I would also recommend checking out bootstrap's scrollspy feature. It sounds like it does what you are trying to achieve. You could either try implementing it instead, or digging into their code and see how they are approaching it and learn something new.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `position >= target` only adds the active class if the user has scrolled below the top of the section, so this will add the class even if the user has scrolled beyond the entire section.

Change

```
if (position >= target)
```

to

```
if (position >= target && position < target + $(this).height())
```

appears to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

hi with small change it worked without any issues

```
  jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
  var position = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
  var classSet = 0;

  jQuery('.section').each(function() {
      var target = jQuery(this).offset().top;

      var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
      if (classSet == 0)
        jQuery('#navbar ul li a[data-id=' + id + ']').removeClass('clicked');
      if (position >= (target - 200) && position < target + $(this).height()) {
          jQuery('#navbar ul li a[data-id=' + id + ']').addClass('clicked');
          classSet = 1;
      }
  });

});
```