# Scrolling animation not applying top the first menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I managed to implement this snippet grabbed here on SO to my WordPress site:
http://scentology.burnnotice.co.za/

```
$("#primary-menu > li > a").on("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var bookMark = $(this).attr("href").substring(1,$(this).attr("href").length);
  bookMarkTag = $("a[name='"+ bookMark +"']");
  if(bookMark !== undefined) {
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: bookMarkTag.offset().top}, Math.floor(bookMarkTag.offset().top));
  }         
});
```

When I click on a menu item,it leads me to the right section perfectly.Only problem is that when I click on the Home item, it scrolls back to the top but the animation does not apply so it goes too fast.
How can apply the animation to the home menu item as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try below code it works for me. you can change **animateSpeed** as you want

```
$("#primary-menu > li > a").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var bookMark = $(this).attr("href").substring(1,$(this).attr("href").length);
    bookMarkTag = $("a[name='"+ bookMark +"']");
    if(bookMark !== undefined) {
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: bookMarkTag.offset().top}, Math.floor(bookMarkTag.offset().top));
    }         
});
```

Replace to

```
$("#primary-menu > li > a").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var bookMark = $(this).attr("href").substring(1,$(this).attr("href").length);
    bookMarkTag = $("a[name='"+ bookMark +"']");
    var animateSpeed = 500;
    if(bookMark !== undefined) {
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: bookMarkTag.offset().top}, animateSpeed );
    }
});
```

Comment: It  works perfectly and I can control the speed in a better way. Mind explaining why the first  code does not work?

Comment: it because if you find click on Home the position function ( Math.floor(bookMarkTag.offset().top) ) gives -15 value that's wy