# Animate menu item with anime.js when scrolling down to section

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, menu, anime.js

I am trying to combine code from [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395988/highlight-menu-item-when-scrolling-down-to-section), with code from [@Luisdanielroviracontreras](https://codepen.io/luisdanielroviracontreras/pen/LYNbwBQ) to make a cool index menu for my portfolio case studies. So far I have been able to animate the item background when clicked:
https://codepen.io/andyradall/pen/BaKJpbM

But as you can see, I run into problems when trying to animate the background of the menu item based on scroll position. The background item ends up in the wrong place: https://codepen.io/andyradall/pen/WNwdRLq

Note. My problem:

1. **specificity** and selecting the right HTML elements in the js.
2. Attaching the active class to the **button** rather than just the **a**
3. Alternatively I need to remove the button and attach the **.effect** to the **a**

Here is the current code for my hightlight navigation section:

```js
// Header Sticky
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("navigation");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}

/* Header buttons Luis that attatches active to buttons on click. */
/*
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.header-navbar button')
const effect = document.querySelector('.effect')

buttons.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
      const x = evt.target.offsetLeft
      buttons.forEach((btn) => { btn.classList.remove('active') })
      evt.target.classList.add('active')
      anime({
          targets: '.effect',
          left: `${x}px`,
          duration: 600,
      })
  })
})
*/

/* header buttons on scroll from @Daniel at stackoverflow that misses the buttons and only attatches the active to the link*/

// caches the navigation links
var $navigationLinks = $('#navigation > ul > li > a');

// what I really want:
/*var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.header-navbar button')
var effect = document.querySelector('.effect')*/

// cache (in reversed order) the sections
var $sections = $($(".section").get().reverse());

// map each section id to their corresponding navigation link
// here i really want to map each section id to the corresponding button
var sectionIdTonavigationLink = {};
$sections.each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    sectionIdTonavigationLink[id] = $('#navigation > ul > li > a[href=\\#' + id + ']');
});

// throttle function, enforces a minimum time interval
function throttle(fn, interval) {
    var lastCall, timeoutId;
    return function () {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        if (lastCall && now < (lastCall + interval) ) {
            // if we are inside the interval we wait
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
                lastCall = now;
                fn.call();
            }, interval - (now - lastCall) );
        } else {
            // otherwise, we directly call the function 
            lastCall = now;
            fn.call();
        }
    };
}

function highlightNavigation() {
    // get the current vertical position of the scroll bar
    var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    const effect = document.querySelector('.effect')
   
    // iterate the sections
    $sections.each(function() {
        var currentSection = $(this);
        // get the position of the section
        var sectionTop = currentSection.offset().top;
        var x = currentSection.offset().top;
        console.log(x);
        // if the user has scrolled over the top of the section  
        if (scrollPosition >= sectionTop) {
            // get the section id
            var id = currentSection.attr('id');
            // get the corresponding navigation link
            var $navigationLink = sectionIdTonavigationLink[id];
            // if the link is not active
            if ($navigationLink.hasClass('active')) {
                // remove .active class from all the links
                $navigationLinks.removeClass('active');
                // add .active class to the current link
                $navigationLink.addClass('active')
               anime({
                targets: '.effect',
                left: `${x}px`,
                duration: 600,
               });
            }
            // we have found our section, so we return false to exit the each loop
            return false;
        }
    });
}

$(window).scroll( throttle(highlightNavigation,100) );

// if you don't want to throttle the function use this instead:
//$(window).scroll( highlightNavigation );
```

```css
/* Global */

* {
  list-style: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  --primary: 25,91,255;
  --color: 44, 62, 80;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #f4f7f8;
 /* height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100); */
 /* overflow: hidden; */
  color: rgb(var(--color));
  width: 100%;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
}

/* .sticky attatch to #navigation on scroll past #navigation */
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.header-navbar ul {
list-style: none;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-evenly;
width: 100%;
background: #fff;
}

.header-navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 24px 8px 24px 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}

.header-navbar button {
  width: 140px;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

/*.header-navbar a {
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}*/

.header-navbar a{
  /*color: #333; */
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* to use if adding back link*/
.header-navbar a:active:not(.float) {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.header-navbar button.active {
  color: rgb(232, 76, 79);
}

/* if icon not text */
.header-navbar button i {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  pointer-events: none;
}

/*background effect*/

.con-effect {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*top: 0px;
  left: 0px;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.effect {
  background: rgba(232, 76, 232, 0.15);
  width: 160px;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

/* Content sections styling */

.hero {
  width:100%;
  padding: 32px;
}

.section{
width:100%;
height: 500px;
padding: 32px;
}

#first {
  background-color: #8face0;
}

#second {
  background-color: #a388e8;
}

#third {
  background-color: #f4769e;
}

#fourth {
  background-color: #8face0;
}

#fifth {
  background-color: #a388e8;
}

#bottom-spacer {
  height: 2200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.0/anime.min.js></script>
<body>
    <main>
        <section id="intro" class="hero">
            <div>
              <h1>This will be the hero section</h1>
            </div>
        </section>    
        <div id="navigation" class="header-navbar">
            <div class="con-effect">
            <div class="effect"></div>
            </div>

            <ul>
            <li><a href="#intro"><button>Introduction</button></a></li>
            <li><a href="#first"><button>1. User research</button></a></li>
            <li><a href="#second"><button>2. Ideation</button></a></li>
            <li><a href="#third"><button>3. Design phase</button></a></li>
            <li><a href="#fourth"><button>4. Testing</button></a></li>
            <li><a href="#fifth"><button>5. Results</button></a></li>
        </ul>    
</div>

        </div>  
               <section class="sections">
                   <section id="first" class="section">
                       <h2>1. User research</h2>
                   </section>    
                   <section id="second" class="section">
                       <h2>2. Ideate</h2>
                   </section>  
                   <section id="third" class="section">
                       <h2>3. Design phase</h2>
                   </section>
                   <section id="fourth" class="section">
                       <h2>4. Testing</h2>
                   </section>
                   <section id="fifth" class="section">
                       <h2>5. Results</h2>
                    </section>                    
                    <section id="bottom-spacer">
                     </section>   
           </section>
</main>
   
</body>
```

Comment: it seems I need to add the buttons back, and figure out how to add the active class to the button? Now it seems the active class is only added to the link?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solve it!
Solution:

1. Find the **active navigationlink offset left**, store it in var **x**
2. Use navigationlink offset left value (**x**) to place the background **effect**

Now, there is only styling and finetuning left :)
Final will receive updates here: https://codepen.io/andyradall/pen/WNwdRLq

```js
// sticky header
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("navigation");
//var effectClass = document.getElementById("effectClass")
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
    //effectClass.classList.add("effect")
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
    //effectClass.classList.remove("effect")
  }
}


// cache the navigation links 
var $navigationLinks = $('#navigation > ul > li > a');
// cache (in reversed order) the sections
var $sections = $($(".section").get().reverse());

// map each section id to their corresponding navigation link
var sectionIdTonavigationLink = {};
$sections.each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    sectionIdTonavigationLink[id] = $('#navigation > ul > li > a[href=\\#' + id + ']');
});

// throttle function, enforces a minimum time interval
function throttle(fn, interval) {
    var lastCall, timeoutId;
    return function () {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        if (lastCall && now < (lastCall + interval) ) {
            // if we are inside the interval we wait
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
                lastCall = now;
                fn.call();
            }, interval - (now - lastCall) );
        } else {
            // otherwise, we directly call the function 
            lastCall = now;
            fn.call();
        }
    };
}

function highlightNavigation() {
    // get the current vertical position of the scroll bar
    var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    const effect = document.querySelector('.effect')

    // iterate the sections
    $sections.each(function() {
        var currentSection = $(this);
        // get the position of the section
        var sectionTop = currentSection.offset().top;
        // if the user has scrolled over the top of the section  
        if (scrollPosition >= sectionTop) {
            // get the section id
            var id = currentSection.attr('id');
            // get the corresponding navigation link
            var $navigationLink = sectionIdTonavigationLink[id];
            // if the link is not active
            if (!$navigationLink.hasClass('active')) {
                // remove .active class from all the links
                $navigationLinks.removeClass('active');
                // add .active class to the current link
                $navigationLink.addClass('active');
                var x = $navigationLink.offset().left;
                anime({
                    targets: '.effect',
                    left: `${x-28}px`,
                    duration: 600,
                    endDelay: 1000,
                })
            }
            // we have found our section, so we return false to exit the each loop
            return false;
        }
    });
}

 $(window).scroll( throttle(highlightNavigation,100) );

// if you don't want to throttle the function use this instead:
// $(window).scroll( highlightNavigation );
```

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  --primary: 25,91,255;
  --color: 44, 62, 80;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #f4f7f8;
 /* height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100); */
 /* overflow: hidden; */
  color: rgb(var(--color));
  width: 100%;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
}

/* .sticky attatch to #navigation on scroll past #navigation */
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.header-navbar ul {
list-style: none;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-evenly;
width: 100%;
background: #fafafa;
}

.header-navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fafafa;
  padding: 2px 0 2px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.06), 
  0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.06), 
  0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.06), 
  0 8px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.06),
  0 16px 32px rgba(0,0,0,0.06), 
  0 32px 64px rgba(0,0,0,0.06);
}

.header-navbar li {
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

/*.header-navbar a {
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}*/

.header-navbar a{
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1rem;
  /*padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;*/
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* :not excludes class for specific use */
.header-navbar a:active:not(.float) {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.active {
  
  color: rgb(232, 76, 79)!important;
}

.header-navbar a:active {
 
  color: rgb(232, 76, 79)!important;
}

/* if icon not text */
.header-navbar a i {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  pointer-events: none;
}

/*background effect*/

.con-effect {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.effect {
  background: rgba(232, 76, 232, 0.15);
  width: 178px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1px;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

/* Content sections styling */

.hero {
  width:100%;
  padding: 32px;
}

.section{
  color: #666;
width:100%;
/*height: 500px;*/
padding: 32px;
}

#first {
  background-color: #8face0;
}

#second {
  background-color: #a388e8;
}

#third {
  background-color: #f4769e;
}

#fourth {
  background-color: #8face0;
}

#fifth {
  background-color: #a388e8;
}

#bottom-spacer {
  height: 2200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
     <main>
        <section id="intro" class="hero section">
            <div>
              <h1>This will be the hero section</h1>
            </div>
        </section>    
        <div id="navigation" class="header-navbar">
            <div class="con-effect">
            <div id="effectClass" class="effect"></div>
            </div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#intro">Introduction</a></li>
            <li><a href="#first">1. User research</a></li>
            <li><a href="#second">2. Ideation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#third">3. Design phase</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fourth">4. Testing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fifth">5. Results</a></li>
        </ul> 
        </div>  
               <section class="sections">
                   <section id="first" class="section">
                       <h2>1. User research</h2>
                   </section>    
                   <section id="second" class="section">
                       <h2>2. Ideate</h2>
                   </section>  
                   <section id="third" class="section">
                       <h2>3. Design phase</h2>
                   </section>
                   <section id="fourth" class="section">
                       <h2>4. Testing</h2>
                   </section>
                   <section id="fifth" class="section">
                       <h2>5. Results</h2>
                    </section>                    
                    <section id="bottom-spacer">
                     </section>   
           </section>
</main>
</body>
```