# How to populate input fields using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

Below is a screenshot of my system which allows me to record payments against invoices (invoices are called tenant charges in my system).

[image]

I have an input labelled 'Total Amount Paid' with a button next to it labelled 'Allocate'. When I click this button, I want the 'Amount Received' inputs to be populated automatically starting with the first to the last. For example, if I entered '200' into the 'Total Amount Received' input and pressed 'Allocate', it would populate the first 'Amount Received' field with '189.59' and the second with '10.41'.

HTML;

```
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Outstanding Tenant Charge Details</legend>
<div style="padding:5px;"><label for="total_amount_paid">Total Amount Paid (&pound;):</label>
    <input type="number" id="total_amount_paid" value="0.00">&nbsp;<button type="button" id="allocate_total_amount_paid">Allocate</button></div>
<table class="solid" style="margin:5px;"><tr>
        <th>Tenant Charge #</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Due Date</th>
        <th>Charge Total</th>
        <th>Amount Paid</th>
        <th>Amount Due</th>
        <th>Amount Received (&pound;)</th><th>Management Fee at 7.00%</th></tr><tr>
        <td><a href="view_tenant_charge.php?tenant_charge_id=217" target="_blank">217</a></td>
        <td>09/11/15</td>
        <td>09/12/15</td>
        <td>&pound;250.00</td>
        <td>&pound;60.41</td>
        <td>&pound;189.59
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_outstanding[]" value="189.59">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="number" name="amount_received[]" class="amount_received" value="0.00" max="189.59" required>&nbsp;<button class="pay_in_full" type="button">Pay in Full</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="tenant_charge_id[]" value="217">
        <input type="hidden" name="tenant_charge_tenancy_id[]" value="69"></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="management_fee_invoice[]" value="1"checked="checked"> <label>Generate &amp; Post Invoice</label></td></tr><tr>
        <td><a href="view_tenant_charge.php?tenant_charge_id=283" target="_blank">283</a></td>
        <td>09/12/15</td>
        <td>09/01/16</td>
        <td>&pound;250.00</td>
        <td>&pound;0.00</td>
        <td>&pound;250.00
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_outstanding[]" value="250.00">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="number" name="amount_received[]" class="amount_received" value="0.00" max="250.00" required>&nbsp;<button class="pay_in_full" type="button">Pay in Full</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="tenant_charge_id[]" value="283">
        <input type="hidden" name="tenant_charge_tenancy_id[]" value="69"></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="management_fee_invoice[]" value="1"checked="checked"> <label>Generate &amp; Post Invoice</label></td></tr></table></fieldset>
```

jQuery;

```
// allocate button

$( "#allocate_total_amount_paid" ).click(function() {

var totalAmountPaid = $("#total_amount_paid").val();

$( ".amount_received" ).each(function( index ) {
  //console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
  alert(index + totalAmountPaid);
});

});
```

Comment: [This is fairly basic JavaScript functionality.](http://api.jquery.com/val/) What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Blazemonger - I know how to set the value of an input field using jQuery. What I can't understand is the logic of how to do it. I'd imagine some type of loop? I haven't tried any code at the moment.

Comment: where is the javascript? Have you tried anything?

Comment: You'd trigger each `input` update by adding a [`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler to the button.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25155384/is-the-sort-order-of-jquerys-each-guaranteed) should help you

Comment: @Blazemonger - Yes, I understand that, what I need help with is the actual code to run when the 'Allocate' button is pressed. I'd imagine the logic is something like looping through each 'Amount Received' field until there are no funds left. I don't know how to do that in jQuery hence my request for help.

Comment: @Blazemonger - I have updated my code with my attempt

Comment: Where is the "Total Amount Received" field? I only see "Total Amount Paid".

Comment: An aside: if you're using `input type="number"`, you might want to add `step="0.01"` to each of those.

Comment: @Barmar - Sorry, it should read "Total Amount Paid", I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, get the amount from the previous column, and subtract it from the total.

```
$( "#allocate_total_amount_paid" ).click(function() {
    var totalAmountPaid = parseFloat($("#total_amount_paid").val());
    $( ".amount_received" ).each(function( index ) {
        var thisAmount = parseFloat($(this).closest("td").prev("td").find("input[name^=amount_outstanding]").val());
        if (thisAmount <= totalAmountPaid) {
            // If we have enough for this payment, pay it in full
            $(this).val(thisAmount);
            // and then subtract from the total payment
            totalAmountPaid -= thisAmount;
        } else {
            // We don't have enough, so just pay what we have available
            $(this).val(totalAmountPaid);
            // Now we have nothing left, use 0 for remaining rows
            totalAmountPaid = 0;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: What does this line do? var thisAmount = parseFloat($(this).closest("td").prev("td").find("input[name^=amount_outstanding]").val());

Comment: Could we use the 'max' attribute of the field instead for this line?

Comment: var thisAmount = $(this).attr('max');

Comment: Yes, you could. I didn't notice that attribute in the HTML.

Comment: `$(this).closest("td")` gets the cell that contains the current input in the loop. `.prev("td")` gets the cell before it. `.find("input[name^=amount_outstanding]")` gets the input whose name begins with `amount_outstanding` in that cell. Which part of this is hard to understand?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

First I'd structure your table into `thead` and `tbody` for more efficient looping, and add a distinctive class name to it, and add a hidden input with the due sum to each row. Here's a basic example.

```js
var sum = parseFloat($('#total_amount_paid').val());
$('.tenants tbody tr').each(function() {
  var due = parseFloat($('.amount_due', this).val());
  var amount = (sum >= due) ? due : sum;
  $('.amount_received', this).val(amount);
  sum -= amount;
});
```

```html
<table class="tenants">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>...</th>
      <th>Amount due</th>
      <th>Amount received</th>
      <th>...</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>
        &pound;123.45
        <input type="hidden" class="amount_due" value="123.45" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="amount_received" />
      </td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```