# Does cypress "get" returns elements in order it appears on HTML document?

Tags: javascript, dom, cypress, e2e-testing

I am writing e2e tests using [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) and I need to write a test that asserts if front-end correctly orders a set of elements.

Only for example, consider I have a page that just list a set of ages as follows:

```html
<div id="list">
   <div class="age">18</div>
   <div class="age">20</div>
   <div class="age">19</div>
</div>
```

And I want to write a test that asserts if it is sorted from older to younger.

One approach could be to get elements in which class is *age* and discover if it is ordered by iterate over them:

```js
cy.get(".age").then((ages) => {
  //check if elements are ordered iterating over ages array
})
```

But I can only guarantee that my test is correct if `ages` array is in the same order as presented in HTML.

Does DOM elements yield by `cy.get()` always are in the exact order that it is put in HTML document?

I can't find any reference to this in [official documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, **yes**.

---

Explanation:

From the cypress doc of [get](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get.html#Syntax):

> The querying behavior of **this command matches exactly how $(…) works in jQuery**.

and the answer to [how jQuery works the order of $()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25165306/14020929):

> ...So the final answer is that yes, I can use **$('.myList li').each() and iterate through the list items in the order that they appear in the DOM.**